# import simplejson - no module named simplejson

Tags: python, json, monkeyrunner, simplejson

my python version is 2.7.14 in windows 7

I have import simplejson with command "`pip install simplejson`"

my code is

```
import os
import platform
import re
import subprocess
import sys
import threading
import simplejson
```

error messge is

```
ImportError: No module named simplejson
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: please check packages installed in your system using ```pip freeze``` command. and verify simplejson installed or not

Comment: already istalled

Comment: but, error code still exists –

Comment: You are messing up with "Circular import" somewhere in your code! However, error can not be reproduced!

Comment: are you using python or monkeyrunner?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download it from here - [simplejson 3.12.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson)
2. Install
3. Enjoy

Comment: Are you using any other versions of Python?

Comment: Can you share the entire error. Also any chance you have a file named simplejson.py anywhere in the directory where your code is stored?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python and pip in your PATH just run the following command in your console.

```
$ pip install simplejson
```

The console will return the following output

```
Collecting simplejson
Downloading simplejson-3.13.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl (68kB)
Installing collected packages: simplejson
Successfully installed simplejson-3.13.2
```